# I have files in a usb drive that would not delete and the terminal is not working nor accepting my password in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have jpeg, jpg and html files in a USB drive that I want to erase and I can't.  They appear with the lock on them.  I tried to change permissions and can't do that neither.  Went to Terminal and it is not responsive at all, not even for my password.  I can only add files, but not edit them as before when I had 12.04

Answer (score 0):

If you instead boot to a live boot cd, you will (probably) be granted overriding superuser status which will permit you to delete those files.

(My assumption is that those files were written on one of your previous installations when your user name and password were different)